# Generating a new dataframe from an existing one using Purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am simulating a dataset and need to create a series of faux transaction data based upon summary customer parameters that I generated in a separate dataframe. I have tried using `lapply()` and variations of `map()` to do this, but I continue to hit errors.

I hate using the `for()` loop. How can I tidy this up and doing in a very R way?

```r
library(tidyverse)

customers <- letters[1:10]
trx <- 1 + rpois(n = 10, lambda = .4)

customer_df <- tibble(customer = customers,
                      transactions = trx)

# The function to create transactions based on the
# parameters provided in the customer_df

create_trx <- function(cid, trx) {

  customer <- rep(cid, trx)
  amount <- rnorm(trx, mean = 25, sd = 2)
  
  rtn_tbl <- tibble(customer = customer,
                    amount = amount)
  
  return(rtn_tbl)
}

# This is the ugly brute force way I can make it work. I'd like
# to use `map()` or a tidyier approach. The output of this
# function is a new dataframe z2. 

for (i in 1:nrow(customer_df)) {
  z <- create_trx(customer_df$customer[i], customer_df$transactions[i])
  if(exists("z2")) {
    z2 <- rbind(z2, z)
  } else {
    z2 <- z
  }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, we can use `pmap` after setting the column names with the argument names or identifiers of the function

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
customer_df %>% 
    set_names(c('cid', 'trx')) %>%
    pmap_dfr(create_trx)
```

Or it can also be done with a anonymous function call without renaming the column names

```
customer_df %>%
      pmap_dfr(~ create_trx(..1, ..2))
```

Comment: This works! And there was much rejoicing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you can use `Map` to apply `create_trx` for each row which will return a list of dataframes that can be combined with `do.call` + `rbind`.

```
do.call(rbind ,Map(create_trx, customer_df$customer, customer_df$transactions))
```

---

If you are interested in `purrr`/`tidyverse` solution you can use `map2_df` which will make the above solution shorter.

```
purrr::map2_df(customer_df$customer, customer_df$transactions, create_trx)

# A tibble: 15 x 2
#   customer amount
#   <chr>     <dbl>
# 1 a          22.4
# 2 b          23.0
# 3 b          24.3
# 4 c          25.6
# 5 c          26.5
# 6 d          24.6
# 7 e          27.4
# 8 e          26.2
# 9 e          24.3
#10 f          24.3
#11 f          27.3
#12 g          21.3
#13 h          23.8
#14 i          26.2
#15 j          23.4
```